# how to configure atom for running Cpp programs?

Tags: atom

** I have installed atom with the help of youtube
   I have installed 
   gpp-compiler, linter, linter-gcc
   **    [atom showeing error while compiling a c++ program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul27F.png)

Comment: So, is the `xterm` package installed on your system? are you able to run `xterm` from the application launcher?

Answer (score 0):

- Open **Settings**, that is **Edit** -> **Preferences**
- Click **Install** button
- Under **Install packages** there is input field. Type `gcc compiler` there and click **Packages**

Also, run the next in terminal:

```
sudo apt install gcc g++ xterm
```